# For $P$ prime ideal, $S$ its complement, $S^{-1}RP$ is the unique max ideal in $S^{-1}R$

Tags: abstract-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Someone else asked a question that seems related to this one here:

[Explanation why $R_P=(S^{-1}R)_{P(S^{-1}R)}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/747065/explanation-why-r-p-s-1r-ps-1r)

However, I'm wrestling with the notation, so I think I'll understand this problem better if someone is willing to answer it directly. Given a commutative ring $R$ with 1, $P$ a prime ideal and $S = R - P$, I need to show $S^{-1}RP$ is the unique maximal ideal in $S^{-1}R$. I could try to show, equivalently, that $S^{-1}R/ S^{-1}RP$ is a field, but I'm not sure if that's going to be helpful here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$S^{-1}R = R_P$ means that everything not in $P$ gets an inverse. The set $PR_P$ is the set of fractions where the numerator is in $P$ (and the denominator is not in $P$ since that's the definition of $R_P$). That is,

$$ PR_P = \left\{ \frac{a}{b} : a \in P, b \notin P \right\} $$

The elements not in $PR_P$ are of the form $a/b$ where both $a$ and $b$ are not in $P$.

If I have such a fraction then I can take the reciprocal $b/a$ since $a \notin P$. What this is telling me is that the elements of $R_P$ which are not in $PR_P$ are **already invertible** in $R_P$. Hence localizing at $PR_P$ does nothing:

$$ R_P = (R_P)_{PR_P}. $$

But more importantly, if $PR_P$ is a proper ideal such that elements not in $PR_P$ are invertible then $PR_P$ *must* be maximal since to increase $PR_P$ would be to add a unit and we would no longer have a proper ideal.

Comment: Instead of $a \notin P$, do you mean $a \in P$, or $b \notin P$?

Comment: @BMac $a/b \in R_P$ means $b \notin P$, $a/b \in PR_P$ means $a \in P$ and $b \notin P$ so $a/b \in R_P - PR_P$ means $a \notin P$ and $b \notin P$. If I have $a/b \in R_P$ and $b/a \in R_P$ then $a \notin P$ and $b \notin P$.

Comment: Never mind, I read too fast. Right, these are elements NOT in $PR_{P}$. Sorry! This is starting to make sense now.